# How can I make sure a string is clean for insertion into javascript Alert('error message')

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, alert

I am trying to display an error to the user of a web page using a javascript alert popup, I currently have the following code to clean the error string:

```
errorMessage.Replace("'", "\'")
```

But this is not sufficient as some illegal characters are not being removed, is there a static method somewhere in the framework that will format my string for clean insertion into html?

**Update**: *my initial question was slightly ambiguous. 
the string needs to be valid as in alert('this is some 'illegal text' that will not popup');
I will try Server.HtmlEncode, hopefully it will do the trick.*

Answer (score 7):

If you have a look at the AntiXSS module in the [Web Protection Library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/), you'll find that it has a `JavaScriptEncode(string)` method for just this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

There's a simple solution...use the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) and "serialize" the string value. By serializing the string to JSON, you're by definition ensuring that it'll work nicely inside an alert statement.

Answer (score 1):

You want to avoid XSS vulnerabilities, which is good. The following cheat sheet should assist you (and also contains a reference to code for escaping the string):

[http://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233_-_JavaScript_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_JavaScript_Data_Values)

Answer (score 0):

To escape a string for clean insertion into html you can use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` method. I'm not sure it this helps you with the javascript.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx

Comment: I quote "that will format my string for clean insertion into html"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET 4 you can use the new <%: %> syntax to HtmlEncode the generated string AND replace the default encoder with AntiXSS, or any other library you may prefer. Phil Haack explains how to do this in [Using AntiXss as the default encoder for ASP.NET](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/06/using-antixss-as-the-default-encoder-for-asp-net.aspx)

This way you can write an alert like this:

```
alert('<%: this.ErrorMessage %>');
```

In previous versions you can use what others have suggested, either HtmlEncode or AntiXss like this:

```
alert('<%= HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(this.ErrorMessage) %>');
```

or

```
alert('<%= AntiXss.HtmlEncode(this.ErrorMessage) %>');
```

Answer (score 0):

`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` will not encode a single quote (') and is not suitable for encoding a string to be used as an alert message.  Personally I do it like this:

```
public static string EscapeAlertMessage(string value)
{
    value = value.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
    value = value.Replace("'", "\\'");
    value = value.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
    return value;
}
```

If your message contains multiple lines, you can replace them by "\n" - e.g. if the lines are separated by Environment.NewLine:

```
value = value.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\\n");
```

Or if you don't know what the separators are (\r\n, \n or \r only) you could use:

```
value = value.Replace("\r", "\\r");
value = value.Replace("\n", "\\n");
```

Comment: This was fixed in ASP.NET 4.0. HtmlEncode now replaces ' with &#39;

Comment: `HtmlEncode` encodes string for use in HTML. To use string in JavaScript string literal, you must encode it as JavaScript string literal, not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help but none of the answers presented gave me the complete solution.

Joe's answer was closest but it did not account for \r\n newline. I could not find a way to translate c# newline into a javascript equivalient.

```
public static string EscapeAlertMessage(string value)
{
  value = value.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
  value = value.Replace("'", "\\'");
  value = value.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
  value = value.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "--");

  return value;
}
```

Comment: JavaScript's newline is just '\n'

Comment: That would be Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\\n");

Comment: A string could contain any type of line break (\n, \r or \r\n) ... shouldn't it be a regex that replaces \r andor \n against a single \\n ?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function in my projects. It escpaes all possible characters for Javascript:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Encodes a string to be represented as a string literal. The format
    /// is essentially a JSON string.
    /// 
    /// Example Output: Hello \"Rick\"!\r\nRock on
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string EncodeJsString(string s)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in s)
        {
            switch (c)
            {
                case '\"':
                    sb.Append("\\\"");
                    break;
                case '\\':
                    sb.Append("\\\\");
                    break;
                case '\b':
                    sb.Append("\\b");
                    break;
                case '\f':
                    sb.Append("\\f");
                    break;
                case '\n':
                    sb.Append("\\n");
                    break;
                case '\r':
                    sb.Append("\\r");
                    break;
                case '\t':
                    sb.Append("\\t");
                    break;
                case '\'':
                    sb.Append("\\'");
                    break;
                default:
                    int i = (int)c;
                    if (i < 32 || i > 127)
                    {
                        sb.AppendFormat("\\u{0:X04}", i);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.Append(c);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```